# How to connect table's columns of same database

Tags: .net, sql, sql-update

I have a database say `database_Employee` with 2 tables, `record` and `salary`.
Now both tables have a column `EmpId`.

What I want is when I update (or add to) `EmpId` value in the `record` table, then `EmpId` column of `salary` should get the value automatically (what I added in `EmpId` of `tb1`).

I am using Visual Studio 2010, .NET Framework 4.0, SQL Server Express.

If my question is not clear, let me know.

Comment: You insert a row into table SALARY, same as you did for table RECORD. How should the system (.net || db) know that it has to insert a row into SALARY. Just a hint: Maybe you don't need the SALARY table, it seems to be a 1:1 relationship to RECORD...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this, where you want to keep two tables values in sync, you should think about triggers.  They would go into the SQL server layer.  Since there don't seem to be any business rules associated with this synchronization, triggers will make sure that the data will be copied from one table to the next, regardless of the program.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brian....i was looking for the same. After some googling on triggers, i got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you want to achieve but:

on option would be to setup a insert/update/delete trigger in the db on the table "record" which in turn changes values in table "salary".

another option would be use a stored procudure for the update/insert... in the stored procedure can access both tables as needed...

Comment: Thanks for the reply Yahia, actually i wanted my columns of 2 tables in a database to sync when changing one of the column. I did already what u suggested about updating both the columns while Insert/Update/Delete. but i was looking for a Synchronizing function.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that. If `EmpId` can change, you should create a new `Id` column in `record`, just for the database. You then have a foreign key column in `salary` that references this `record.Id`. This way `salary` doesn't need `EmpId`. If you want to get the `EmpId` for a certain `salary` column, you join on the `Id` column. If you want to change `EmpId`, just change it on `record`, that's enough.

This assumes you have a good reason to keep the table separate. Another option would be to combine them into one table.

**EDIT:**

Based on a comment to this answer (which makes it a completely different question, I think):

If, as you say, manager creates the `Details` row and after that, HR adds his `Accounts` data, then there is no reason to create the `Accounts` row when you create the `Details` row. Create the row when the HR sets the account data for the first time.

Another solution (already proposed by others) is to merge the two tables. If you always have 1: relationship between them, there is no need to keep the data in different tables. You could create views if you wanted to look only at a part of the data.

Yet another solution, which comes closest to what you are asking (but may not be the best option) is to use triggers. When a row is inserted into the `Details` table, a trigger fires and a row is created in the `Accounts` table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Svick, actually i cant change EmpId", it is set to auto increment....I can just delete and create records(which in turn create EmpId for me). I think Triggers is the way to go for me, to Sync 2 tables in a database

Comment: @user, if it is autoincrement, how come you are changing its value!?

Comment: sorry, but i am not changing its value. i just want that autoincremented value to sync automatically with the other table.

Comment: Based on what? I though you had two rows in two tables with the same `EmpId` and you wanted to change both at the same time. That doesn't seem to be the case, so what is?

Comment: ok, let me be more specific. i have a database named "Employees". I have 2 tables in it-"Details" and "Accounts". In details table i store employee details. In Accounts table i store their salary stuff. I have Empid column common in both the tables. now when i add a employy in table "Details", a Empid gets generated automatically. now i want that EmpId should get updated (rather created) in "Accounts" table automatically. Just imagine, my manager is adding new employees data (in details table of course) and HR is handling salary stuff. So, i hope both tables must have same Empid.

Comment: may i ask why did u say Triggers is not the best option??

Comment: Because I don't see any reason to use them. All they seem to do here is to add unnecessary complexity.